# Detect with powershell if windows has fully loaded

Tags: windows, powershell

I have created an unattend.xml file that, upon finishing the installation, starts a PowerShell script. However, I am encountering a problem as the script launches before the desktop is fully loaded (win10 and win11 images).

The script removes some apps and applies some regedit tweaks.

I'm using this workaround :

```
while ($true) {
    $process = Get-Process -Name OneDrive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($process) {
        Write-Host "OneDrive is running."
        break  
    }
    
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 
}
```

It works but I was wondering if there's a better approach.
Thanks.

Comment: Your workaround looks pretty good